# Regex expression for string parsing in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following string:

```
Value >= 50000 && Value < 80000 && Code = 'AB'
```

I have to handle `5000`, `8000` and `SSCD`. how should I use regex? I used the following example, couldn't produce output.

```
var str = 'Value >= 50000 && Value < 80000 && Code = "AB"';
var m = Regex.Match(str, @"(\d+).(\d+).*?(\d+)");
```

Comment: Could you describe the rules for what you intend to match? Is it just any value that appears after a comparator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks terrible, but works (basically your average regex):

```
(&&|\|\|)?\s*((?:\w+\.)+\w+)\s*([<>]=?|!?=)\s*('(?:\\'|[^'])*(?:(?<!\\)')|\d+)
```

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/GwCeuN/4)

I think the "Explanation" section on regex101 should give an overview on how that works. Tell me on the comments if you need further explanation.

---

The match groups there will be:

1. The logical operator (&&, ||, or null)
2. The variable name with the `.` separators (e.g.: `Request.Amount.Value`)
3. The comparator (<, >, <=, >=, !=, =)
4. The value (a number or a string delimited with `'`. `"` does not work).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:[!><=]\s)([A-Za-z0-9']+)
```